# jQuery ajax post doesn't redirect to php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a contact form on my website with a jQuery ajax call, but I don't see the .php page when I click on the button.

Here's the ajax call:

```
    var data = {
        name: $("input.userName").val(),
        email: $("input.userEmail").val(),
        tel: $('input.userPhone').val(),
        message: "Projet de "+$("input.userName").val() + ", Tel : " + $('input.userPhone').val(),
            body: body
        };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "acerola.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            console.log('ajax sucessfully sent');
        }
    });
```

With acerola.php:

```
<html>
<head><title>PHP Mail Sender</title></head>
<body>
<h1>OUIIiiii</h1>
<?php

echo "<h1>Coucou</h1>";

/* All form fields are automatically passed to the PHP script through the array $HTTP_POST_VARS. */
$name = $HTTP_POST_VARS['name'];
$email = $HTTP_POST_VARS['email'];
$tel = $HTTP_POST_VARS['tel'];
$message = $HTTP_POST_VARS['message'];
$body = $HTTP_POST_VARS['body'];

/* PHP form validation: the script checks that the Email field contains a valid email address and the Subject field isn't empty. preg_match performs a regular expression match. It's a very powerful PHP function to validate form fields and other strings - see PHP manual for details. */
if (!preg_match("/\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/", $email)) {
  echo "<h4>Invalid email address</h4>";
  echo "<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>";
} elseif ($subject == "") {
  echo "<h4>No subject</h4>";
  echo "<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>";
} elseif ( /* Sends the mail and outputs the "Thank you" string if the mail is successfully sent, or the error string otherwise. */
    mail("plu@gmail.com", "Demande de devis web", $message . $body, "From:" . $email)
) {
  echo "<h4>Thank you for sending email</h4>";
  echo "<div>Thank you for sending email</div>";
} else {
  echo "<h4>Can't send email to $email</h4>";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the user to be redirected to `acerola.php`. But the user stays on the original page.

Comment: How looks ajax `data` ?

Comment: No need for ajax if you want to redirect just submit your data to the `acerola.php`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki how to do this properly please ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I am adding the data in my question

Comment: You need to use this: `data: JSON.stringify(data),`, because you need to send data to server as a string.in `acerola.php` you have to parse json using `JSON.parse()`, and then the problem is done.

Comment: what ? Since web data only takes strings ?? Data should be able to be an object !   And on the php side, do you json_decode() instead of JSON.parse() ?

Answer (score 2):

After the ajax response, fire a redirect with javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "acerola.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        console.log('ajax sucessfully sent');
        window.location.replace('URL HERE')
    }
});
```

Comment: But there is html code as you can see in my php script and I want this code to display first, but it doesn't go to this page .php

Comment: If I do this, the variables do not echo in the php page...for example `echo $name`displays nothing....why ??